# Nextflow: filtering channel with values from other channel

Tags: operators, filtering, nextflow

I have a multi-output channel producing as one output list of "1" and empty strings. I'd like to use these values to filter another output with the corresponding datasets (1=invalid, empty=valid). For better context:

```
channel.datasets = [data1, data2, data3, data4]
channel.status = ['1','1','','']
```

What I'd like to have is the following:

```
valid_datasets = [data3, data4]
invalid_datasets = [data1, data2]
```

I expected this to be relatively simple, but I think I'm not fully into the Nextflow logic yet.

What I tried to do was to first associate the ones and empty strings to boolean values:

```
invalid = channel.status.map { it == "1" }
valid = channel.status.map { it != "1" }
```

And then use these boolean values for filtering:

```
invalid_data = channel.datasets.filter(invalid)
valid_data = channel.datasets.filter(valid)
```

Unfortunately this didn't work.
I also considered using `branch` but I can't find a way to use the `status` channel as a way to branch the `datasets` channel.
Note that I'd like to keep the `datasets` channel separate because I'll need to process datasets on their own downstream. Beforehand I tried to use `tuple` to combine `status` and `datasets`, but I couldn't find a way to access only `datasets` after filtering.

I would appreciate any suggestion or recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that these two channels do not share a matching key. They *could* be 'combined' using the [`merge`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#merge) operator and then filtered, but this approach is likely ***not*** what you want (emphasis mine):

> In general, the use of the `merge` operator is discouraged. Processes and channel operators are not guaranteed to emit items in the order that they were received, due to their parallel and asynchronous nature. Therefore, if you try to merge output channels from different processes, the resulting channel may be different on each run, which will cause resumed runs to not work properly.
>
> **You should always use a matching key (e.g. sample ID) to merge multiple channels, so that they are combined in a deterministic way. For this purpose, you can use the [join](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#join) operator.**

If the upstream processes instead produced channels with a shared key (or the keys could be associated in some way), they could be joined and branched to get what you want, for example:

```
workflow {

    datasets_ch = Channel.of( ['foo', 'data1'], ['bar', 'data2'], ['baz', 'data3'] )
    status_ch = Channel.of( ['bar', '1'], ['baz', ''], ['foo', '1'] )

    datasets_ch
        .join( status_ch )
        .branch { key, dataset, status ->
            valid: status
                return tuple( key, dataset )
            invalid: !status
                return tuple( key, dataset )
        }
        .set { result }

    result.valid.view { key, dataset ->
        "Valid dataset: ${dataset} (${key})"
    }
    result.invalid.view { key, dataset ->
        "Invalid dataset: ${dataset} (${key})"
    }
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `main.nf` [dreamy_roentgen] DSL2 - revision: 959ee8cd84
Valid dataset: data2 (bar)
Invalid dataset: data3 (baz)
Valid dataset: data1 (foo)
```